# JQuery not working if only 2 of 3 Ajax returns are Json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I got following problem.

I wrote an ajax request,my PHP file does some checks and returns either an array which i echo with json_encode() or a normal echo. It depends on what is the result of the checks my PHP file makes. My problem is following:

When i give my Ajax request `dataType: "json"` it seems that it is only working if i return some `json_encode($array)` from my PHP file. If i echo normal data the Jquery won't work.

A little example:

```
$.ajax(
            {
                type: "get",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "check_basket.php",
                data: {bought : bought, pid : pid, cid : cid, csid : csid, lang : lang},
                success: function(data){    
                            if(data.status == '1'){
                                alert(data.b);
                            } else if(data.status  == '2'){
                                alert(data.b);
                            } else {
                                 $("#dropdown_shopping_cart_inner").html(data);
                                 $('#head_shopping_cart').load(document.URL +  ' #head_shopping_cart');
                                 $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideDown(800);
                            }
                }
            }
        );
```

In my PHP i say something like this:

```
if(get_date_last_purchased($pid) == true){
    $arr = array('status' => 1, 'b' => 'test1');
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
elseif($bought > $row0['gm_max_order']){
    $arr = array('status' => 2, 'b' => 'test2');
    echo json_encode($arr);
} else {
    echo "everything ok";
}
```

If one of the frist two cases happens and status 1 or 2 get returned to my JQuery, everything works fine. But when the third PHP condition happens and my PHP just returns echo without `json_encode`, the Jquery simply does nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Setting dataType to json, jQuery will parse result to JSON. `"everything ok"` isn't valid JSON. Return instead valid one

Comment: No matter how complicated your php is, NEVER mix data types.... each endpoint should use the same format...

Comment: Just for clarification: A response containing only `"everything ok"` *is* a valid JSON-response (It's a JSON string). Just `everything ok` (without double quotes) is not. As for an answer, as AlexK says, always return JSON encoded data if your app expects to receive that, if using `dataType`, be sure to send a `Content-Type` header containing `application/json` explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.

1. **Client Side:** Remove the `dataType: "json"` from there.
2. **Server Side:** Add `json_encode("$output")` here. Also you can send an empty or `null` value wrapped inside `[]`, because jQuery executes it as a script.

For a solution in Server Side, I would say:

```
echo '["everything ok"]';
```

Comment: The thing is my PHP file is more complex than i wrote above, there are happening some database queries and after each query there is some "echo" made, how would i wrap all this in json?

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski So what, use the client side! `:)` `JSON.parse` will work for non JSON output too. So try it out.

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski Yes, they will work. It is kind of *backward compatible*.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you explicitly request a json.

Try the shorter notation to be able to work with either data type

```
$.get("check_basket.php",function(data){
//Do whatever you want to do with your data
}
```

But your problem is, that you're mixing different types together... Any endpoint should only return the same data type and the same format, so instead I'd recommend oyu changing your PHP

```
if(get_date_last_purchased($pid) == true){
    $arr = array('status' => 1, 'b' => 'test1');
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
elseif($bought > $row0['gm_max_order']){
    $arr = array('status' => 2, 'b' => 'test1');
    echo json_encode($arr);
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>0));
}
```

and change your jQuery code like this:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "check_basket.php",
            data: {bought : bought, pid : pid, cid : cid, csid : csid, lang : lang},
            success: function(data){    
                        if(data.status == 1){
                            alert(data.b);
                        } else if(data.status == 2){
                            alert(data.b);
                        } else if(data.status == 0 ) {
                             $("#dropdown_shopping_cart_inner").html(data);
                             $('#head_shopping_cart').load(document.URL +  ' #head_shopping_cart');
                             $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideDown(800);
                        }
            }
        }
    );
```

also, when checking for status 2, you're checking `data == 2` instead of `data.status == 2`

Combine this with the short get statement, clean up your code, and you should be fine with this:

```
$.get('check_basket.php',function(data){
switch(data.status){
 case 0:
     $("#dropdown_shopping_cart_inner").html(data);
     $('#head_shopping_cart').load(document.URL +  ' #head_shopping_cart');
     $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideDown(800);
 break;
 case 1:
    alert(data.b);
    break;
 case 2:
    alert(data.b);
    break;
  }
});
```

or even shorter:

```
$.get('check_basket.php',function(data){
  if(data.status == 0){
     $("#dropdown_shopping_cart_inner").html(data);
     $('#head_shopping_cart').load(document.URL +  ' #head_shopping_cart');
     $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideDown(800);
  } else{
    alert(data.b);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `dataType` altogether and let jQuery figure it out.

Construct your return messages properly to handle both success and failures also.

Assign status codes from 10 to 20 for success and from 0 to 9 for failures

For success

```
print json_encode(array(
    'status' => 11,
    'message' => "all is good"
);
```

For failure or error

```
print json_encode(array(
    'status' => 4,
    'message' => "some things are not so cool"
));
```

Adjust your `success` callback to handle both types of return

```
success: function(data){
    // check if you have a success or failure
    if (data.status > 10){
        console.log(data.message);
    }
    else {
        alert(data.message);
    }
}
```